# Member function pointers as normal function pointers without `std::mem_fn`

Tags: c++, templates, casting, functor, pointer-to-member

I'd like to have something like this:

```
struct Foo {
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T i) const { /* ... */
    }

    template <typename T>
    auto To() const {    // Doesn't work!
        return this->*static_cast<void (Foo::*)(int) const>(&Foo::operator());
    }
};
```

Basically, I'd like to obtain a functor from a member function pointer. The above code would have worked if instead of `operator()` I had used a static function (having gotten rid of all the `this->*` and `Foo::` parts). If I only return the member function pointer `auto ptr = static_cast<void (Foo::*)(int) const>(&Foo::operator())`, I can use it, e.g., by providing a `Foo*` pointer `foo` as `foo->*ptr(0);`: this motivates `this->*` in the above code. **Is there a nice way to achieve this objective without resorting to lambdas?** I'd like to just return a function pointer that "embeds" the information of the specific `Foo` instance from which it was created.

P.S.: I don't want solutions with lambdas because I'm only curious about solutions without them.

Comment: What about [`std::mem_fn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn)?

Comment: What you are looking for is this: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hnnYzj61j But do note that lambdas are literally nothing but synctactic sugar for that pattern, so there's no reason whatsoever to not use them instead.

Comment: From their previous question, it's clear that OP wants the equivalent of a capturing lambda, so std::mem_fn and the like don't apply.

Comment: @Frank I really like your solution, it's what I was looking for, i.e., some sort of wrapper class. I'd be happy to accept it as the answer to my question!

Comment: @fdev At the risk of repeating myself. This is literally just doing the exact same work the compiler is required to do when using a lambda while polluting the namespace. Don't do that. Just use a lambda.

Comment: I'll definitely use lambdas, but I was just curious about an alternative solution! Thanks again!